# Button id cannot be accessed through onClick event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table of data, each row having a button with a unique id. The onClick event handler is supposed to log the button id to the console. However, the id is logged to console only sometimes.

```
<Button id={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>
     Click
</Button>
```

```
handleClick = e => {
    console.log('button id', e.target.id);
  }
```

The 'button id' text is logged to console each time the button is clicked, but the id (e.target.id) is logged to console only sometimes. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Which Button component are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The avaliblity of `target.id` on the click handler's event will depend on the implementation of the `Button` component that you're using here.

In the simple case, if you were using a "native" `<button>` (note the lower case "b") then your current approach would work as expected:

```
{/* Using the "native button" here */}
<button id={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>Log id</button>

handleClick = e => {
    // Native button will pass id value of element to e.target 
    console.log('button id', e.target.id);
}
```

Because you're using a `<Button>` component, the avaliblity of `target.id`  in your `onClick` callback will depend on the implementation of this `<Button>` component (ie wether or not it passes a value for an `id` prop to the clickable element to produce the desired result)

A work around (which avoids implemntation specific issues noted above) would be to revise your code to something like:

```
{/* Define local arrow function, pass index in scope as second argument */}
<Button id={index} onClick={ e => this.handleClick(e, index) }>
     Click
</Button>

/* Extend function signature to take explict id argument */
handleClick = (e, id) => {
    console.log('button id', id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the nativ event.target.

Try this:

```
<Button id={index} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)}>
     Click
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<Button id={index} onClick={this.handleClick(this, index)}>
     Click
</Button>
```

and then

```
handleClick(e, id) {
    console.log('button id', id);
  }
```